# Using xquery FLWOR expressions to find multiple "where" restrictions

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0, flwor

I am trying to find employees who work on projects located in Houston but the department the project is housed in is not located in Houston.  I was trying to model the expression after [this](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery_primer.html) example of FLWOR expressions but the query doesn't return anything and it should return results.

edit: Here is the [input](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/elna-lab-2010/ch7/7.2/company.xml).

```
xquery
let $doc := doc("~path/company.xml")
for $e in $doc//employee,
    $d in $doc//department,
    $p in $doc//projects
where $d/locations[location!="Houston"]
and $p/project[plocations="Houston"]
return <e>{$e/fname}{$e/lname}{$e/address}</e>
/
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the XML document.

Comment: Sorry I added the input file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `for` clause is enough; otherwise, you'll iterate over all employees several times:

```
let   $doc := doc(...)
for   $e in $doc//employee
let   $p := $doc//project[@pnumber = $e/projects/worksOn/@pno]
where $p[plocation = 'Houston']
  and $doc//department[@dno = $p/@controllingDepartment]
                      [not(locations/location = 'Houston')]
return <e>{ $e/fname }{ $e/lname }{ $e/address }</e>
```

Comment: Sorry I added the input file.

Comment: Slightly edited; this version of the query will be evaluated faster by some XQuery processors (such as BaseX).

Answer (score 2):

A single XPath 2.0 expression can select all wanted employees:

```
/*/employees
     /*[projects/*/@pno
       =
        /*/projects/*
               [plocation eq 'Houston'
              and
                boolean
                (for $dn in @controllingDepartment
                  return
                   /*/departments/*
                       [@dno eq $dn
                      and
                        not(locations/location
                          =
                           'Houston'
                           )
                       ]
                )
               ]/@pnumber
       ]
```

Comment: Is XPath better in some way than using XQuery?

Comment: Actually, the only advantage using pure XPath is that you may also use it with processors that don’t support XQuery.

Comment: @mnky9800n: @_Christian Grün answered your question. In a senses, being able to express something in pure XPAth makes your solution ultimately more portable. For example, you can evaluate this XPath expression not only with your XQuery processor (XPath is a subset of XQuery) but also in any XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 XSLT processor or in any stand-alone XPath 2.0 or 3.0 engine (Alas I am aware only of PsychiPath).

Comment: @mnky9800n: Also some people prefer the tighter syntax of XPath over the "verbose" XQuery. XPath becomes even more attractive in 3.0 with the higher-order functions (HOF) and the ability to define inline, anonymous function items. My guess is that for 4.0 we'll seriously need an .xpath file extension and an "import clause" for XPath. (: Hope this comes soon  :)

Answer (score 1):

Typo: `and $p/project[plocation="Houston"]`

You had an "s" too much: was `plocations`.

Comment: Hmm, this produces a lot of replication.  I tried `distinct-values(query above)` but it says there is a syntax error however it is recommended to do it that way from [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702764/xquery-distinct-values-with-where-clause-problem).